# Java read from a text file

Tags: java, user-interface, import

I'm trying to load some data to a GUI from a text file using a scanner. I have two sections in my text file: Clubs and Members. The code runs okay for the Clubs section. For example, if I have 4 clubs in my list, all of them will be displayed, but for the Members section doesn't matter how many members are in the list, only the first member will be displayed. Here is my code:

```
public void load (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
     FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Clubs.txt");
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);

     while (scan.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            if(line.equals("Members")){
                String firstName = scan.next();
                String lastName = scan.next();
                Pupil p1 = new Pupil( firstName, lastName);
                pupils[nbrPupils] = p1;
                nbrPupils ++;

               }   
             else if(line.equals("Clubs")){ 
                 while (scan.hasNext()){
                 String club = scan.nextLine();
                 Club aNewClub = new Club(club);
                 clubs[nbrClubs] = aNewClub;
                 nbrClubs ++;

                }

        }
```

Comment: can you give me an example for the input in the text file??

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have made some minor edits to your post to make what you are asking more apparent to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you're doing `while (scan.hasNext())` in the `Clubs` section, but you don't do so in the `Members` section.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But if I'm using a while loop in the Members section as well the program won't run and I don't know why...this is where I got stack

Comment: What do you mean by "don't run"? Keep in mind that a `while (scan.hasNext())` will never exit the loop until the file is finished. Consider adding condition `!line.equals("Clubs")` to the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

convert from `while` loop  to `if` condition because you just want to check if there is a next line

```
else if (line.equals("Clubs")) {
       if (scan.hasNext()) {/////here if you use while loop , it will loop until the file is finish 
         String club = scan.nextLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ReadFile().load("");
    }

    public void load (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Clubs.txt");
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
         boolean membersfound =false;
         while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scan.nextLine();

                if(line.equals("Members") || membersfound){

                    String firstName = scan.next();
                    String lastName = scan.next();
                   System.out.println("Member   "+firstName +":"+ lastName);

                   }   
                 else if(line.equals("Clubs") ){ 
                     while (scan.hasNext()){
                     String club = scan.nextLine();
                     if( club.equals("Members")){
                         membersfound = true;
                         break;
                     }
                     System.out.println("Clubname :" + club
                             );                

                    }

            }
}
    }
}
```

I could have modified the whole program . But i wanted to show you your mistake
Sample clubs.txt file
Members
member1
member2
member3
Clubs
club1
club2
club3

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried to modified the code as you suggested, but doesn't work. I'm stack again :)

Answer (score -1):

When you do `scan.nextLine()` it moves the scanner to the line after the one you currently read in. So if you continue to do `scan.next()` the scanner will start from the end of your current line (in this case `line`) and reads what's after it.

[See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) it says:

"Advances this scanner past the current line and **returns the input that was skipped**"

What you can to is just call `split()` or `substring()` on `line` and extract the information you need.

Comment: split and substring have nothing to do with the question being asked here.

Comment: @m0skit0 My answer says that "Members" section doesn't work because that his code moves the scanner too far away. To avoid that, I suggest using split and substring. At what point they have nothing to do with the question?